# 502 Bad Gateway for NGINX USWGI and Django app

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, uwsgi

I am having issues running this locally. I have two containers in my app. The Django app and the nginx server. Below are the config files and dockerfiles. I am getting a 502 on the localhost:8000 and the error message is

2021/11/16 01:18:29 [error] 23#23: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.30.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8888", host: "localhost:8000", referrer: "http://localhost:8000/"

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"   
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: test_deploy_web
    hostname: blindspot
    command: uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - staticfiles:/app/static/
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: test_deploy_nginx
    volumes:
      - staticfiles:/app/static/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  staticfiles:
```

app dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

nginx dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY my_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/

RUN mkdir -p /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/\
    && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/\
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my_nginx.conf

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream blindspot {
     server 127.0.0.1:8888;
    #server unix:/app/app.sock; # for a file socket
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen    80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name localhost; 
    
    # Django media
    # location /media  {
    #     alias /usr/src/app/static/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    # }

    location /static {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass blindspot; 
        include uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }

}
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = /app/blindspot/wsgi.py 
socket = 127.0.0.1:8888
master=true# maximum number of worker processes
processes = 4
threads = 2# Django's wsgi file
module = blindspot.wsgi:application 
vacuum=true
```

Comment: nginx is forwarding to `127.0.0.1:8888`, which is the local address of the nginx container. You need to forward to the address of the web container. They aren't the same.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I'm all crossed up. I have nginx forwarding to the docker I created in the app with the uwsgi.ini file, I'm trying to have nginx point to the container port.

Comment: You have to expose port in Dockerfile, then nginx can be able to connect to that port. `8888` nginx trying to connect to this, but this is not exposed from dockerfile.

Comment: Thanks Jinna. I have updated the dockerfile to include an expose of 8888. That didn't work, I then updated the uwsgi.ini to make the socket 0.0.0.0:8888.